# How to make my main Dart app object accessible from browser console?

Tags: debugging, browser, dart, dartium

I want to debug my app in Dartium, call its methods, like `APP.getUserState()` from browser console.

With JavaScript I would just make `APP` global this way `window.APP = myAPP`.

How do I achieve the same effect with Dart app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**web/index.dart**

```
class X {
  static void p() => print('xxx');
  static void q(String a) => print(a);
}

void main() {
  // your application code
}
```

Ensure the context is set to Dart and start using Dart classes:

[image]